# How to create new database having some tables from old database in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
DB1
Flight Master
Source_Flight
Destination_Flight
Customer_Data
```

Now I want to create a new DB having only first 3 tables. How can I do it?? I don't want to make a copy of it and drop tables which I don't need

PS:- This is not the actual DB ,this I have taken as example .Actual DB is having so many tables.

Comment: but in this way I have to do it for all the tables which I want to copy.I don't want to do it like this

Comment: No you can add more than one table in mysqldump command.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is export with mysqldump.

Dumb you database structure to file`mysqldump --no-data -u someuser -p mydatabase > script.sql`

edit your script and execute it an your new instance.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way..

```
1.Export the database you have as sql format.
2.Change the database name as you want in the downloaded sql file and remove the unwanted table also from it.
3.And import the new edited sql file.
```